# Dividing processes evenly among threads

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, division

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to divide a number of processes as evenly as possible over a number of threads.  Each process takes the same amount of time.
The number of processes can vary, from 1 to 1 million.  The threadCount is fixed, and can be anywhere from 4 to 48.

The code below does divide all the work evenly, except for the last case, where I throw in what is left over.
    Is there a way to fix this so that the work is spread more evenly?

```
    void main(void)
{
    int processBegin[100];
    int processEnd[100];
    int activeProcessCount = 6243;
    int threadCount = 24;

int processsInBundle  = (int) (activeProcessCount / threadCount);
int processBalance    = activeProcessCount - (processsInBundle * threadCount);

for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
{
    processBegin[ i ] = i * processsInBundle;
    processEnd[ i ]   = (processBegin[ i ] +  processsInBundle) - 1;
}

processEnd[ threadCount - 1 ] += processBalance;


FILE *debug = fopen("s:\\data\\testdump\\debug.csv", WRITE);
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
{
    int processsInBucket = (i == threadCount - 1) ? processsInBundle + processBalance : processBegin[i+1] - processBegin[i];
    fprintf(debug, "%d,start,%d,stop,%d,processsInBucket,%d\n", activeProcessCount, processBegin[i], processEnd[i], processsInBucket);
}
fclose(debug);
```

}

Comment: Give the first `activeProcessCount % threadCount` threads `processsInBundle + 1` processes and give the others `processsInBundle` ones.

Comment: This is not a solution, but it is some [relevant reading](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/load-balance-and-parallel-performance) on the topic of Load Balancing threads (Load balancing an application workload among threads)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
{
    int processsInBucket = (i == threadCount - 1) ? processsInBundle + processBalance : processBegin[i+1] - processBegin[i];
    fprintf(debug, "%d,start,%d,stop,%d,processsInBucket,%d\n", activeProcessCount, processBegin[i], processEnd[i], processsInBucket);
}` R u trying to Declare a `int` variable for every iteration in the loop? Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the first `activeProcessCount % threadCount` threads `processInBundle + 1` processes and give the others `processsInBundle` ones.

```
int processInBundle  = (int) (activeProcessCount / threadCount);
int processSoFar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < activeProcessCount % threadCount; i++){
    processBegin[i] = processSoFar;
    processSoFar += processInBundle + 1;
    processEnd[i] = processSoFar - 1;
}
for (int i = activeProcessCount % threadCount; i < threadCount; i++){
    processBegin[i] = processSoFar;
    processSoFar += processInBundle;
    processEnd[i] = processSoFar - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the same problem as trying to divide 5 pennies onto 3 people. It's just impossible unless you can saw the pennies in half.

Also even if all processes need an equal amount of theoretical runtime it doesn't mean that they will be executed in the same amount of time due to kernel scheduling, cache performance and various other hardware related factors.

To suggest some performance optimisations:

- Use dynamic scheduling. i.e. split your work into batches (can be size 1) and have your threads take one batch at a time, run it, then take the next one. This way the threads will always be working until all batches are gone.
- More advanced is to start with a big batch size (commonly `numwork/numthreads` and decrease it each time a thread takes work out of the pool). OpenMP refers to it as guided scheduling.